# Github Actions not working giving error Invalid type for `on`

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration

When I am pushing my project on github it pipeline should work but it's telling Invalid type for `on`

```
name: NASA Project CI
on:
  push: branches:[master]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js version 16
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with: node-version:'16'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build --prefix client
```

Answer (score 3):

YAML, the format that GitHub uses for Actions, is sensitive to space and indentation.  You'll probably want to write the `push:` entries on separate lines, indented, like so:

```
name: NASA Project CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js version 16
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with: node-version:'16'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build --prefix client
```

Comment: Thank you. However now another problem happens . install command not working in workflow just after 5 or 6 min its telling  Process completed with exit code 137

Comment: That's a separate question that should be answered separately.  I can answer this one, but not that one, and if you ask a separate question with suitable error messages, someone capable will probably help.